# Shortcuts, Suggestions When Using Static Wrappers for Direct Function Calls to Ubiquitous Interface-Wrapped Classes?

Tags: c#, templates, interface, components, multiple-inheritance

So I've (mostly) wrapped my head around C#'s componentization paradigm and why that's a superior (more predictable, flexible) alternative to confusing and quasi-unpredictable multiple inheritance of c++.

However, I have a couple things that are trouble me.

So if I understand correctly the general approach to adding a component is:

1. Create an interface that has that component of name `I<ClassName adjective>`

   ```
   public interface IHasGear { Gear gear { get; set; } }
   public interface IBladeEquipped { Blade blade { get; set; } }
   ```
2. Create an extension class that calls appropriate methods in the interfaced classes.

   ```
   public static class GearExtensions
   {
       public static void Stop(this IHasGear machine)
       {
           machine.gear.KineticStop();
       }

       public static void Accelerate(this IHasGear machine)
       {
           machine.gear.ApplyAngularAcceleration();
       }
   }
   public static class BladeExtensions
   {
       public static void Cut(this IBladeEquipped machine)
       {
           machine.blade.Cut();
       }

       public static void ReSharpen(this IBladeEquippeded machine)
       {
           machine.blade.ReSharpen();
       }
   }
   ```
3. And then finally add the interface reference and instance of the referenced class to my class that uses the selected component.

   ```
   public class MeatGrinder : IHasGear, IHasBlade
   {
       public Gear oldToothyOne { get; set; }
       public Blade mrPointy { get; set; }

       public MeatGrinder() { oldToothyOne = new Gear(); mrPointy = new Blade();}
   }
   ```

Now my couple of questions:

1. Why ALWAYS force the instantiation of the var?

   I understand that you might want this if there is inheritance, as you could implement the var with different children. But what about the simplest case of non-inheritance?  Why not build in an automatic mechanism to auto-implement in the compiled code the base class(es) in the interfaces is (are) implemented if they are not explicitly implemented
2. Is there a way to template this process in a ubiquitous fashion?

   Obviously this is a repetitive task, if you have several components.  Given the ambiguity, is there a way to streamline the workload??
3. Is there a superior componentization(/inheritance) scheme to the method I describe?

   Things to keep in mind:

   - There's only a few component classes.
   - I want to be able to use the component class functions as direct calls in the composited class.
   - There are multiple composited classes (component classes << composited classes)
   - The components are dissimilar and thus not appropriate for unification in one class.
   - Given the above considerations an approach that forces me to write individualized code for each composited class is not a desirable approach.

**EDIT 1:**

I shouldn't have been ambiguous.  The reason why I'm not using direct inheritance here is because I have multiple "key" components with functionality that I want to be able to directly address ubiquitously and publicly... e.g. I want to be able to say:

```
     Machine myMachine = new Machine();
     myMachine.Accelerate();
     myMachine.Cut();
     myMachine.ReSharpen();
```

Hopefully that helps to clarify my question and why I'm adopting this scheme.

Also, I had a couple errors in my example code (a var was non-public and my naming was consistent... these have been corrected.

**EDIT 2:**

Things that don't make sense for me (to my understanding):

a) Abstract Classes

*Why?*  No multiple inheritance

b) Implicit Operators, a la, [hcb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640888/hcb)'s suggestion:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10072/Simulated-Multiple-Inheritance-Pattern-for-C

*Why?* This approach requires you to create operators for ever class utilizing the component classes, which would result in much more code in a scheme where the interface is commonly used.  To me if you're going to go that route, just make traditional wrapper functions rather than get all fancy.

My need for a more elegant solution is driven by ubiquity and mass use of a couple common components that perform redundant functionality, but are dissimilar and thus inappropriate to lump in a single class (despite the convenience that would provide).

**Edit 3:**

Props to [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) for showing me how to format my code nicely without edit diving! :)

Retitled the question to make it more clear, added more precise requirements for suggesting alternate solutions.

Comment: Have you tried refactoring tools like e.g. [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)?

Comment: No... relatively new to C-Sharp, but am building a framework, so needed some ubiquitous components, hence how I came to this feature of the language.  Would you recommend ReSharper and does it fulfill some of my above needs (or offer a superior alternative to the outlined approach?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is just an attempt to emulate multiple inheritance. I don't think it's “the general approach to adding a component”.

I don't think what you're doing is a good way of using extension methods, it looks more like an anti-pattern to me. Especially since you're doing it just to save a few keystrokes, it doesn't add you any other benefit.

I think the answer to your questions about why you can't use some simpler way to do that is that C# tries to be **explicit** and **consistent**.

Explicit in that it won't guess what you mean, it makes you spell it out. This is because its guess could be very easily wrong. And the rules how exactly does it guess would probably have to be very complicated and thus confusing. (“I made this little change and now my code behaves completely differently.”)

Another thing is consistency: if you usually implement interface one way, but sometimes you do it differently, it makes the language more complicated and more confusing. Of course, there are cases where inconsistencies like this are worth it.

Specifically, if the feature of automatic implementation of properties from interfaces would work, your code would compile, *but wouldn't work correctly*: `IBladeEquipped` defines the property `blade`, but your class contains the property `mrPointy`. The compiler would see that you don't implement the required property and implement it for you. And then your code would fail with a `NullReferenceException`, because `blade` will always be `null`. So I think your code presents a good argument against that feature.

Also, I think your example is actually quite good at explaining why you *shouldn't* write the code the way you want. If you want to resharpen the knife of a meat grinder, do that: `grinder.blade.Resharpen()`. Writing it differently would feel less natural and more confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for but i like to couple interfaces with abstract base classes to implement default methods and properties:

```
public interface IHasGear { Gear gear { get; set; } }

public abstract class BHasGear : IHasGear { public virtual Gear gear { get; set; } }

public class MeatGrinder : BHasGear 
{ 
    //no need to implement gear, the abstract class already implemented it
    private Gear oldToothyOne { get; set; } }
}
```

Comment: Hi hcb... but can you inherit simultaneous from multiple abstract classes??

e.g.
`public class MeatGrinder : BHasGear, BHasBlade`??

I need to be able to use multiple interfaces!

Comment: If I understand correctly, wouldn't a multiple inheritance of abstracted classes be illegal... I guess I should have put two utilized interfaces (blade and gear) in my description, but I thought that would be implied by the fact that I'm not simply inheriting! :)

Comment: It's true you can only inherit from one (abstract) class but from multiple interfaces. There should be some kind of design pattern for this

Comment: here it is: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10072/Simulated-Multiple-Inheritance-Pattern-for-C

Comment: @hcb... true that is flexible, it's a lot more work than the approach I outline above, in the case where you have a small # of commonly used interfaces (say a lot of things with `Gear` or `Blade` components), but a # of classes using those interfaces.  Thus the code you posted will work (much like the code above), but to my understanding it would make my life more difficult, not simpler.